# PHP File Download Counter Invalid Link Because Of Characters?

Tags: php

I have a script that I would like to edit.
It basically downloads files and counts it and then displays it as expected. The only problem is that when I am using a file that has characters in it, it throws `invalid file` error instead of downloading.

When I have a file named (GREGZYY-SUCK-iT-AN-SEE-2O16.zip) for example, it downloads the file. But, when I have a file named (RyanJones - F.N.T ( For GG, KyleMorris & Murdo.zip) 16) it throws me `invalid file` error.

Below are the files and the code I have:

```
index.php
download.php
files folder & a counters folder
```

index.php is as follows:

```
<?php 
function get_download_count($file=null){
$counters = './counters/';
if($file == null) return 0;
$count = 0;
if(file_exists($counters.md5($file).'_counter.txt')){
    $fp = fopen($counters.md5($file).'_counter.txt', "r");
    $count = fread($fp, 1024);
    fclose($fp);
}else{
    $fp = fopen($counters.md5($file).'_counter.txt', "w+");
    fwrite($fp, $count);
    fclose($fp);
}
return $count;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="./download.php?file=filenameziphere.zip">filenameziphere</a>     (Downloaded <?php echo get_download_count('filenameziphere.zip');?> times)    <br>
<a href="./download.php?file=filenameziphere2.zip">filenamehere</a> (Downloaded <?php echo get_download_count('filenameziphere2.zip');?> times)    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

download.php is as follows:

```
<?php 

$downloads_folder = './';
$counters_folder = './counters/';

if(!empty($_GET['file'])){
$file = basename($_GET['file']);

if(file_exists($downloads_folder.$file)){

    if(file_exists($counters_folder.md5($file).'_counter.txt')){
        $fp = fopen($counters_folder.md5($file).'_counter.txt', "r");
        $count = fread($fp, 1024);
        fclose($fp);
        $fp = fopen($counters_folder.md5($file).'_counter.txt', "w");
        fwrite($fp, $count + 1);
        fclose($fp);
    }else{
        $fp = fopen($counters_folder.md5($file).'_counter.txt', "w+");
        fwrite($fp, 1);
        fclose($fp);
    }

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-    check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf("%u",     filesize($downloads_folder.$file)));

// http headers for zip downloads
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".sprintf($downloads_folder.$file));
ob_end_flush();

    $fh = fopen($downloads_folder.$file, "rb");
    while (!feof($fh)) {
        echo fgets($fh);
        flush();
    }
    fclose($fh);
    exit;
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit('File not found!');
}
}
?>
```

I tried changing the `utf charset` to `utf-8` at times and other pieces, but still nothing is working. Any help is appreciated and if possible a shorter code.

Comment: If the second one is what you are having issue with there no extension at the end. I am not sure 100% that is it but might be a place to look.

Comment: yes, i believe it is the download.php that i am having the issue on.

Comment: No sorry this file (GREGZYY-SUCK-iT-AN-SEE-2O16.zip) has .zip at the end this: (RyanJones - F.N.T ( For GG, KyleMorris & Murdo.zip) 16) has 16. not sure about the parentheses too but that could be a cause.

Comment: oh, no thats just because i left it out, they are all zip files and all marked up correctly on the files i have.
I have a feeling it is something to do with the utf charset but not 100%

Comment: I do not have a php dev environment handy but if this is not resolved later tonight I will take a look at it.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this with what was provided here. Can you give me the file name exactly as they are on the server and in the links.